# Integrate if condition during .read_csv read out to Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

```
def dataDownSampled(data,resolution,startDate):
    parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    series = pd.read_csv(data, sep = ';', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, 
    squeeze=True,date_parser=parser)
    downsampled = series.resample(resolution)
    mean = downsampled.mean()
    return mean
    #mean.to_csv(filename+'.csv',sep=';')
```

The function above read a "data" file. The first column of this file contains a time. The parser function is putting it in the exact format. 
This column could contain dates which are more in the past than the argument "startDate" coming with the argument of the definition "dataDownSampled".

**Is it possible to integrate a condition in the function .read_csv so it popes all dates smaller than "startDate"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put a condition in `read_csv` function. Instead, after your read_csv runs, and your dataframe is created, you can filter the df with `dates > start_date`. Like this:

Let's say this your dataframe:

```
In [156]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[156]: 
        date
0 1973-08-31
1 2017-11-17
2 2009-02-13
3 2018-07-03

In [162]: start_date = '2010-01-01'
In [163]: df[df['date'] > start_date]                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[164]: 
        date
1 2017-11-17
3 2018-07-03
```

Comment: Mayank: thank you very much! Implemented and working.

Comment: Pleasure but where I do this?